# вывод в show из соединительной таблицы

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Привет! 
есть 3 модели (RailwayStation, Route и джоин таблица RailwayStationsRoute)

```
class RailwayStationsRoute < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :railway_station
  belongs_to :route 

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :railway_stations_routes
  has_many :railway_stations, through: :railway_stations_routes

class RailwayStation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :railway_stations_routes
  has_many :routes, through: :railway_stations_routes
```

задача: во вьюхе Route (show.html.erb) вывести список станций по порядковому номеру (station_number - поле интеджер в соединительной таблице)

если во вьюхе show написать код:

```
<% @route.railway_stations.each do |station| %>
<%= station.railway_stations_routes.inspect %><%= station.title %>
```

выведет:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<RailwayStationsRoute id: 2, railway_station_id: 2, route_id: 1, station_number: 2>]Saint-Petersburg
```

где присутствует station_number

но если inspect изменить на station_number то выкинет ошибку:

```
undefined method `station_number' for #<RailwayStationsRoute::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc3cffe3ef0>
```

тк нет метода station_number у модели railwayStation

далее создал скоуп в соедидительной таблице:

```
scope :ttt, -> { select('railway_stations.*, 
               railway_stations_routes.station_number') }
```

изменил код во вьюхе на:

```
<%= station.railway_stations_routes.ttt %><%= station.title %>
```

выводит:

```
#<RailwayStationsRoute::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fc3cff15190>Saint-Petersburg
```

вопрос в том Как облагородить этот самый вывод? что бы показывало цифру (station_number)

Comment: или скоуп написан не верно?

Answer (score 2):

У вас здесь проблема скорее с наложением предметной области на программирование, чем непосредственно с программированием.

С вашим скоупом проблема в том, что у одной модели внезапно возникли поля от другой. Пункт маршрута внезапно приобрёл черты вокзала. Если б у вас были нужные для вывода методы в модели вокзала, у пункта маршрута, полученного таким образом, их бы не было.

Уберите этот скоуп. Совсем. В нём нет необходимости, при этом от него есть прямой вред.

---

Попробую сломать ваше заблуждение: вы выводите **не станции**. Вы выводите **пункты маршрута**, каждый из которых связан с одной станцией.

Посему, вам ничто не мешает сделать так:

```
<% @route.railway_stations_routes.each do |rsr| %>
<%= rsr.station_number %><%= rsr.railway_station.title %>
```

...кроме, разве что, соображений производительности, а именно проблемы N+1 запроса.
Но об этой проблеме и её решении вам обстоятельно расскажут [гайды](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Но, коротко, вот:

```
<% @route.railway_stations_routes.includes(:railway_station).each do |rsr| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

в итоге:

вьюха show (route) - ttt вызываю на цикл each

```
<% @route.railway_stations.ttt.each do |station| %>
<%= station.station_number %> - <%= station.title %>
```

railway_station.rb - перенес скоуп сюда

```
scope :ttt, -> { select("railway_stations.*, 
railway_stations_routes.station_number") }
```

Comment: Вы явно не прочитали или не поняли мой ответ, раз не избавились от этого скоупа совсем.

Comment: Прошу прощения!! изначально сделал ошибку пробуя Ваш способ! 
Все работает! 
в RailwayStation есть еще скоуп с сортировкий станций в маршруте по порядковому номеру, который как понимаю нужно перенести в RailwayStationsRoute и поднастроить (я совсем зелен в программирование еще)

Comment: Верно, да. Станции странно сортировать по тому, что к ним однозначно не относится.